# How can I change an image based on URL hash when using fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I am currently using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for a [website I'm creating](http://192.185.103.115/~luke/selfstoragedemo/). Notice how as you scroll, it appends a hash to the URL (ie. `#feature1`). I would like to change an image or a background image based on that hash

This is above my `<body>` tag to initialize fullPage.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['welcome', 'feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6'],
            sectionsColor: ['transparent', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C', '#C63D0F', '#1BBC9B', '#7E8F7C'],
            navigation: true,
            navigationPosition: 'left',
        });
    });
```

I am using this javascript to try and change the image, although I'm pretty sure `document.write` is wrong.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Which anchor is being used?
      switch(window.location.hash) {
         case "#feature1":
           document.write('<img class="screen" src="img/bg-feature-2.jpg">');
         break;
         case "#feature2":
           document.write('<img class="screen" src="img/bg-feature-1.jpg">');
         break;
      }
    });
```

If I scroll to the #feature1 or #feature2 it does nothing. However, if I type the URL with the hash directly into the browser, it shows just the image and nothing else. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The fullpage plugin offers multiple callback methods such as `afterSlideLoad` and `onSlideLeave`. Utilizing these would be the best way to implement what you want into your existing code. Just look at the [documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) for examples.

Comment: Paul, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Brian Ray you should be using fullpage.js callbacks for it.

You can use [`afterLoad`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) or `onLeave` for sections and `afterSlideLoad` or `onSlideLoad` for slides.

For example:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        var loadedSection = $(this);

        //using anchorLink
        if (anchorLink == 'secondSlide') {
            alert("Section 2 ended loading");
        }
    }
});
```

Although in your case I would directly do it in CSS by using the css class of the type `fp-viewing-section-slide` that fullpage.js adds to the `body` element.

Check out [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M) where it explains how to use it.

For example:

```
body.fp-viewing-firstPage #myImage{
    background: url('demo.gif');
}

body.fp-viewing-secondPage #myImage{
    background: url('otherImage.gif');
}
```

Comment: I used your CSS method instead of using the callbacks. It's smooth and works like a charm. As always, I over complicated things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `hashchange` event - there's [documentation over at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange).

But basically you use it like this:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  // called whenever the hash changes
  // put your switch / case here.
}, false);
```

The problem with your `$(document).ready()` approach is, that it is only run once after the page is loaded (actually, once the document is ready). And not later. The change of the url hash is not loading something, it's just jumping you to a different "fragment" of the same document.

Comment: There's a much better approach using fullpage.js features.

Comment: Yeah, well, if you consider a standards compliant pure JavaScript solution that works without any plugin and across browsers inferior, then I really can't help you. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: He is asking for a specific problem with his site which is using fullPage.js. Your solution is not the way go to in this case, it won't be as flexible as using the plugin's callbacks.

Comment: One could also argue that you're locking him further into a library, even though the functionality - in this described case - is trivially achieved without any third party code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your page to the `hashchange` event:

```
$(function(){

  // Bind an event to window.onhashchange that, when the hash changes, gets the
  // hash and adds the class "selected" to any matching nav link.
  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;

    // Change the image link using the following code:
    // $(".screen").attr("src", "img/bg-feature-2.jpg");
    switch(window.location.hash) {
      case "#feature1":
        $(".screen").attr("src", "img/bg-feature-2.jpg");
        break;
      case "#feature2":
        $(".screen").attr("src", "img/bg-feature-1.jpg");
        break;
    }
  })

  // Since the event is only triggered when the hash changes, we need to trigger
  // the event now, to handle the hash the page may have loaded with.
  $(window).hashchange();

});
```

I used [The hash is blank](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/) as a reference.

Comment: Far from ideal. Using the plugin callbacks is the way to go for it.